# Wordpress Cron not Running

Tags: wordpress, cron

I am using the following method to get cron to work with wordpress. It has worked in the past but recently (around December of 2019) it stopped working. It hasn't become too big of a problem until recently.

/usr/local/cpanel/3rdparty/bin/php /home/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/bin/cli.php -s SITE -u USERNAME -p PASSWORD -e Job -a execute

The error that i get from cPanel is:

PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '?' in /home/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/bin/cli.class.php on line 214

Can anyone help me figure out what to do.

Comment: Do you have any special characters in the username/password? Looks like and escape character problem (you could try surrounding the Username/Password in double quotes).

Comment: I do not have any special characters but I attempted to use double quotes and it didn’t help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That could be an old version of php.  Assuming you are on current CiviCRM then try setting your php version to 7.3 See https://docs.civicrm.org/installation/en/latest/general/requirements/#php

Comment: My hosting provider only allows up to PHP version 7.2.26

Comment: Check that /usr/local/cpanel/3rdparty/bin/php is actually 7.2  Sometimes there are different executable names for different versions - eg .../bin/php7.1 ../bin/php7.2

Comment: The Null Coalescing Operator has been available since PHP 7.0 https://www.php.net/manual/en/migration70.new-features.php#migration70.new-features.null-coalesce-op

Comment: I suspect Aidan is right and that your command line PHP is not 7+

Comment: I checked with my hosting provider. They had me update the file path to usr/local/bin/php72